# create an alert for the date and time stored into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, time, alert

I made a todo list where through a datepicker dialog fragment and a fragment timepickerdialog have the possibility to set the date and time and store them in a sqlite database together with the related notes. Now I would like to have the ability to set alerts for date and time when I click in a button image. How should I proceed? My main interest is to understand how to set the alarm so that it fires depending on the date or time stored in the sqlite db. I accept any advice. If anyone is interested I can send the code.

Comment: Yes, everyone is interested in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  can use  alarmmanager and  set it  for the first date to run 
after alarm occured  you must set alarm to next date from your sqlite
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: In theory I'd like to take through a cursor the data field (or time it's the same) and then my idea was to compare the date field in the database with the current date that provides the system. so if the dates match the alarm fire.So in my mind I know what to do but do not know how to do it. For example might need to use a service and a receiver? I need to save the alert into database?

Comment: alarm manager helps you to do a job at specific date and time so if you query from your db order by date and get first record then you can set alarm for that time . you must use a service to get the alarm from system . and in your service you can do your job and at the end set new date for alarm base on your db